# Previous and Next Category

Tags: category, product-list, magento-1, list.phtml

I have looked all over the internet but I could find only Next and Previous for products, but I want to have it at the bottom of category page where all the products (`list.phtml`) are listed.

I have attached a sample below. The example is from `25,000 - 50,000 Gallons` category so before it is `700 - 25,000 Gallons` category and `50,000 - 100,000 Gallons` after it.

[image: Next and Previous Category]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the prev/next categories have the same parent as the current category you can do this:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$prev = null;
$next = null;
if ($currentCategory) {
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $parentId = $currentCategory->getParentId();
    $position = $currentCategory->getPosition();
    $prevCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentId) //filter by same parent id
        ->addAttributeToFilter('position', array('lt' => $position)) //get only categories with position smaller than current one
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'DESC') //sort by position descending
        ->setPageSize(1) //limit query to 1 item
        ->setCurPage(1);
    $firstElem = $prevCollection->getFirstItem(); 
    if ($firstElem) {
        $prev = $firstElem;
    }

    $nextCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentId)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('position', array('gt' => $position))
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->setCurPage(1);
    $firstElem = $nextCollection->getFirstItem(); 
    if ($firstElem) {
        $next = $firstElem;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
<?php if ($prev) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $prev->getUrl();?>">
         <?php echo $this->__('Back to %s', $prev->getName())?>
    </a>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($next) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $next->getUrl();?>">
         <?php echo $this->__('Continue to %s', $next->getName())?>
    </a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Both Next and Previous links shows Previous one.

Comment: @KevinS. Sorry. I had a typo but Prashant fixed it. Try getting the code again.

Comment: I wanted to Thank you but it is considered as spam here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will helps you

```
<?php
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$parentId = $currentCategory->getParentId();

if ( $parentId)){
   $children = $categoryModel->getCategories($parentId); //get all children of parent category of current category
    $catIds = array();
    foreach ($children as $category) {
        $catIds[] =  $category->getId();        
    }
    $key = array_search($currentCategory->getId(), $catIds);

        if($catIds[$key-1]){            
            $previousCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catIds[$key-1]);
            echo "<a href=".$previousCategory->getUrl($previousCategory)." >".$previousCategory->getName()."</a>";
        }
        if($catIds[$key+1]){
            $nextCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catIds[$key+1]);
            echo "<a href=".$nextCategory->getUrl($nextCategory)." >".$nextCategory->getName()."</a>";
        }

}
```

Comment: this might work, but is there a need to load all the child categories just to get the previous and next categories and load the full categories? This will impact performance.

Comment: this works, but it is really slow if you have 100+ categories